Can the sandbox concept be improved? Part 2: Tags
Background
This is a followup question to: part1/subforum:
A subform seems to be not realizable (that easily, it is probably not just like adding a repository to GitHub) - if you have other information, please post in part1, not here!
...But what about tags?
Focus / Identified Solutions (so far)

Headline-Tags like "[STAGE] Can I have blue aliens?"
Alternatives could be [DRAFT] or [SANDBOX]
Normal-Tags as they are below the question
Featured-Tag as in making the question "featured" and show up in the box on the top-right corner.


I do not deem this list exhaustive. Please feel free to edit the post and add more or leave a comment.

Question
Is it deemed a viable solution to tag "pre-stage" questions so they are allowed to "live" within the normal WB:SE?
Please feel invited to state which of the provided solutions you (would) prefer as part of your answer. It is not necessary though.
Purpose
The goal is still to have an improvement to the Sandbox-Concept so that:

A pre-stage question can be handled as a question
Pre-stage improvements can be handled as an answer
Tracking of status, commenting and "discussion" can be done in the comments (per answer) or in chat (isolated from other pre-stage questions).
The auto-notification feature can aid to support the "workflow"
The questions can be filtered and discovered as usual with the "Questions"-tab and filtering

I should mention that in order to release the question "into the wild", all answers and comments would/should/could? be deleted and have a pristine question ready for being answered.
Best Answers

Consider "ease-of-use"
Consider "feasibility" of the proposed "workflow"
Might hint at estimated/increased workload for mods/users
Concerns are welcome


This doesn't work, either

"Headline" tags is a programmatic change to how the entire Stack Exchange network operates. Worldbuilding.SE isn't an independent website. It's operated under the framework of the entire Stack Exchange network. Changing how question titles works changes them for every Stack in the system. Again, this would need to be asked for on meta.stackexchange.com. So, no, we can't do this.

Having independent questions in Meta rather than a single Sandbox question where trial questions are posted as "answers" to the sandbox question is nightmarish. The current Sandbox is the fifth iteration of Worldbuilding's Sandbox. Iterations occur because after enough "answers" have been posted the efficiency of the Sandbox web page decreases and eventually becomes difficult to load and manage. My point is that enough questions get asked that it would clog meta and render it nearly useless for any other purpose. Yes, that might be an argument for creating a sandbox.worldbuilding.com subdomain — I just don't expect Stack Exchange to do it because only a handful of Stacks use sandboxes.

No, it isn't viable or possible to "pre-stage" questions on Main. All questions on Main are subject to the rules Stack Exchange, Inc. created without exception. You could visit Meta.SE and ask there if it's viable (it would be the correct place to ask the question) but this is a fundamental change to how Main works across each and every Stack and I expect it won't get much traction.


BTW, when it comes to questions about how the Stack Exchange software works, you're asking in the wrong place.

Well, I thought, because there is a "self-made" sandbox, this concept could be improved. I have more insight now. Thank you!
